# Trainining with TFrecords gets slower gradually

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to use a TFrecord file for training a network in tensorflow. The problem is that it starts running fine, but after some time, it becomes really slow. Even the GPU utilization goes to 0% during some time.
I have measured the time between iterations, and it is clearly increasing.
I have read somewhere that this might be due, to adding operations to the graph in the training loop, and that that can be solved by using graph.finalize().

My code is like this:

```
    self.inputMR_,self.CT_GT_ = read_and_decode_single_example("data.tfrecords")

    self.inputMR, self.CT_GT = tf.train.shuffle_batch([self.inputMR_, self.CT_GT_], batch_size=self.batch_size, num_threads=2,
        capacity=500*self.batch_size,min_after_dequeue=2000)

    batch_size_tf = tf.shape(self.inputMR)[0]  #variable batchsize so we can test here
    self.train_phase = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase_train')
    self.G = self.Network(self.inputMR,batch_size_tf)# create the network
    self.g_loss=lp_loss(self.G, self.CT_GT, self.l_num, batch_size_tf)
    print 'learning rate ',self.learning_rate
    self.g_optim = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.g_loss)
    self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

Then I have a training stage that looks like this:

```
def train(self, config):
    init=tf.initialize_all_variables()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads=tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
        sess.graph.finalize()# **WHERE SHOULD I PUT THIS?**

        try:

            while not coord.should_stop():
                _,loss_eval = sess.run([self.g_optim, self.g_loss],feed_dict={self.train_phase: True})
               .....

        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]

            print "Exception !!!", e
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()

        coord.join(threads)
        sess.close()
```

When I add the grapgh.finalize, there is an exeption that says: type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'
Could anyone explain to me, what is the correct way to using a TFrecord file during training, and how to use the graph.finalize() without interefering in the QueueRunner execution?

The full error is:

```
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "main.py", line 35, in main
    gen_model.train(FLAGS)
  File "/home/dongnie/Desktop/gan/TF_record_MR_CT/model.py", line 143, in train
    self.global_step.assign(it).eval() # set and update(eval) global_step with index, i
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 505, in assign
    return state_ops.assign(self._variable, value, use_locking=use_locking)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 45, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 490, in apply_op
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 657, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 180, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 167, in constant
    attrs={"value": tensor_value, "dtype": dtype_value}, name=name).outputs[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2337, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2078, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

Comment: Typically you construct the graph, then finalize it, then do your first session.run call. It would be useful to see full stack trace for your RuntimeError

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav, I do that, the problem comes when using the QueueRunner, then the graph.finalize causes an error.
 how can I print the full stack trace?

Comment: ie, copy paste everything that's printed, not just `'exceptions.RuntimeError' ` part

Comment: I added it to the question; but without the try except, otherwise it would only show exceptions.RuntimeError

Comment: So that explains why your training gets slower -- running `global_step.assign(it)` will add a new assign op to the graph each time it gets run

Comment: thanks now I can do graph.finalize(), but then, how could I update the global_step, so that when I load it (with saver.restore) it get also the last itaration it saved? Btw, please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: you should save your assign op as `assign_op = global_step.assign(it)` before `finalize` and run `eval` on `assign_op`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying graph between `session.run` calls. You pin-point the place you are modifying the graph by calling `finalize` on default graph which would trigger an error on graph modification. In your case it seems that you are modifying it by calling `global_step.assign(it)`, which creates an additional assign op each time. You should instead call it once in the beginning, save result to a variable and reuse that value.